# Unable to create reference for the node having non-latin characters in firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database for my project.
The problem is when I set the reference to a key having non-latin text ( ex : `यूजर` ). I get `null` in the data.

Database:

```
यूजर:
  |--नाम:"नाम"
  |--पता:"मुंबई"
  ........
  ........
```

Code:

```js
onValue(ref(db,"/यूजर"),(s)=>{
console.log(s.val()); // shows null
}
```

Weather I am doing it wrong or should I try some different approach?

**Edit**

When i viewed `ref(db,"/यूजर");` object.

```js
_orderByCalled: false
_path: Object
    pieceNum_: 0
      pieces_: Array(1)
       0: "à¤¯à¥‚à¤œà¤°" // /यूजर has been changed to à¤¯à¥‚à¤œà¤°
     length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
_queryParams: Object
_repo: Object
```

**Edit 2**

Ok so the whole mistake was just due to incorrect encoding of non-latin characters.

I added
`<meta charset="UTF-8" />` and voila it worked perfectly.